# Hidden field id is not showing correcly in second page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am a beginner in jQuery dataTable, last day I implement dataTable 1.10 in my website.

[image]

I try to popup the id field in alert window in the selected row.

[image]

The first page is works correctly but when I go to the second page I click the

row id is 11. but popup is showing the id of the clicked row is 1.

[image]

All pages are showing this error, it's only working correctly in first page.

Please see my code below.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$("#tblProvider").dataTable().destroy();

    $("#tblProvider").dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        bPaginate: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        bSort: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("JsonGetAllTariffPosition", "Admin")',
        aoColumns: [
             { sTitle: "Id", bVisible: true, bSortable: false },
             { sTitle: "Number", bSortable: false },
             {
                 sTitle: "Action",
                 bSortable: false,
                 mRender: function (o) { return '<i class="ui-tooltip fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" style="font-size: 22px;" data-original-title="Edit"></i><i class="ui-tooltip fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: 22px;" data-original-title="Delete"></i>'; }
             }
        ],
    });

    $("#tblProvider").on('click', 'tr td i[class="ui-tooltip fa fa-pencil"]', function () {

        var row_index = $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex //you need to determine this how ever you like
        var table = $('#tblProvider').DataTable()
        var column_data = table.row(row_index).data()[0];

        alert(column_data);
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<table id="tblProvider"
                                class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-highlight table-checkable"
                                data-search="true"
                                data-paginate="true">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>Tariff Position</th>
                                        @*<th>General Tax</th>
                                        <th>Consumption Tax</th>*@
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: have you checked in viewsource if hidden rows are there or not. If not then why don't you read first column text instead of index?

Comment: i belive that your problem o happen cause you declare event on in table id, when data table jquery refresh that table is renewed. Try change event for the element has your hidden field. Hope works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code in your click handler with this

```
var node =  $(this).closest('tr')
var table = $('#tblProvider').DataTable()
var column_data = table.row(node).data()[0];
```